# Unwanted leading . in session cookie's domain

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to use `session_set_cookie_params()` to send my session cookies with the HttpOnly and Secure flags: `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', $cookie_domain, true, true)`. However, when I do this, the domain on my cookies start with a leading `.`. I do *not* want my session cookie to be sent to any subdomains, so this is not desired behavior.

I have tried setting `$cookie_domain` to

1. `$_SERVER(HTTP_HOST)`
2. `preg_replace('/^\./', '', $_SERVER(HTTP_HOST))`
3. A string literal containing my domain name

All with the same result. Meanwhile the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) suggests that this should only happen if the leading `.` is intentionally added.

If I do *not* call `session_set_cookie_params()` with the `$domain` parameter, I don't have this problem (the cookie is set for the domain name without the leading `.`), but then I can never get to the `$secure` and `$httponly` parameters.

What might I be doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

While I still hope for a better answer, I have found a workaround for now. Instead of using `session_set_cookie_params()`, I am using

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
```

to set the Secure and HttpOnly flags without needing to pass the domain name to `session_set_cookie_params()`.